# Group dictionary keys and values that are not in sequential order

Tags: python, dictionary

Below I have a list of dictionaries:

```
dict = [{'name': 'Sector',
  'entity': 'ORG(100.0)',
  'synonyms': "Sector:['sector', 'sphere'], , ",
  'definition': 'Sector'},

  {'name': 'Community Name',
  'entity': 'PERSON(39.74)',
  'synonyms': "Community:['biotic_community', 'community', 'community_of_interests', 'residential_area', 'residential_district']",
  'definition': 'Community'}]
```

How do I add a new key that groups entity, and definition as values?

desired output (category is the new added key):

```
dict = [{'name': 'Sector',

  'category': {

  'entity': 'ORG(100.0)',
  'definition': 'Sector'},

  'synonyms': "Sector:['sector', 'sphere'], , "},

  {'name': 'Community Name',

  'category':{

  'entity': 'PERSON(39.74)',
  'definition': 'Community'},

   'synonyms': "Community:['biotic_community', 'community', 'community_of_interests', 'residential_area', 'residential_district']"}]
```

I have tried `[{'name': i.pop('name'), 'category': i}  for I in dict]` but it only works for keys that are in sequential order, how can I modify it to so that I can select certain keys since `entity` and `definition` are not next to each other?

Comment: is the intention only to add `category` key and have the keys `(entitiy, definition, synonyms)` inside it?

Comment: Yes but its only for entity and definition, not synonyms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need

```
data = [{'name': 'Sector',
  'entity': 'ORG(100.0)',
  'synonyms': "Sector:['sector', 'sphere'], , ",
  'definition': 'Sector'},

  {'name': 'Community Name',
  'entity': 'PERSON(39.74)',
  'synonyms': "Community:['biotic_community', 'community', 'community_of_interests', 'residential_area', 'residential_district']",
  'definition': 'Community'}]

subkeys = ['entity', 'definition']
result = [{'category': {k: i.pop(k) for k in subkeys},  **i}  for i in data]
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'category': {'definition': 'Sector', 'entity': 'ORG(100.0)'},
  'name': 'Sector',
  'synonyms': "Sector:['sector', 'sphere'], , "},
 {'category': {'definition': 'Community', 'entity': 'PERSON(39.74)'},
  'name': 'Community Name',
  'synonyms': "Community:['biotic_community', 'community', "
              "'community_of_interests', 'residential_area', "
              "'residential_district']"}]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and great solution. I am wondering is there a way to change the order of the keys? Since after the function the category key is at the top.

Comment: Yes you can..there multiple question with ans to this in stackoverflow. Its a pretty common que :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to transform each object, in which case I would opt for a map with a custom function.

```
import json

dicts = [
    {
        'name': 'Sector', 
        'entity': 'ORG(100.0)', 
        'synonyms': "Sector:['sector', 'sphere'], , ", 
        'definition': 'Sector'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Community Name', 
        'entity': 'PERSON(39.74)', 
        'synonyms': "Community:['biotic_community', 'community', 'community_of_interests', 'residential_area', 'residential_district']", 
        'definition': 'Community'
    }
]

def map_func(item):
    item['category'] = {'entity': item['entity'], 'definition': item['definition']}
    item.pop('entity')
    item.pop('definition')
    return item

mapped_dicts = map(lambda x: map_func(x), dicts)
print(json.dumps(list(mapped_dicts), indent=2))

[
  {
    "name": "Sector",
    "synonyms": "Sector:['sector', 'sphere'], , ",
    "category": {
      "entity": "ORG(100.0)",
      "definition": "Sector"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Community Name",
    "synonyms": "Community:['biotic_community', 'community', 'community_of_interests', 'residential_area', 'residential_district']",
    "category": {
      "entity": "PERSON(39.74)",
      "definition": "Community"
    }
  }
]
```